# How to invoke a class method in google app script from client side?

Tags: class, google-apps-script, web-applications, client-server

How to invoke a class method  in google app script from client side ?
//client side

```
function myClientSideFun() {
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).myClass.myClassMethod()    
function onSucces(msg) { console.log(msg) } 
 }  

//server side
class MyClass {
myClassMethod() { return "myMsg" }
 }

let myClass = new MyClass()
```

Comment: Use [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code. [Test formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) before posting questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple example of using an object method.

**HTML_Test**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="testParam" type="text">
    <script>
      (function () {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
          function(param) {
            document.getElementById("testParam").value = param;
          }
        ).getTestParam();
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Code.gs**

```
class TestObject {
  constructor(param) {
    this.param = param;
  }
  get getParam() { return this.param; }
}

var obj = new TestObject("hello");

function getTestParam() {
  return obj.getParam;
}
```

**Options 2**

To build on what @Bede noted there are many ways to use server side objects.

**HTML_Test**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="testParam" type="text">
    <script>
      (function () {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
          function(param) {
            document.getElementById("testParam").value = param;
          }
        ).getTestParam({name: "getParam2"});
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Code.gs**

```
class TestObject {
  constructor(param1,param2) {
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.param2 = param2;
  }
  getParam1() { return this.param1 }
  getParam2() { return this.param2 }
}

var obj = new TestObject("hello","goodbye");

var getTestParam = param => { return obj[param.name](); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you export the class method in a different top level function, it is not possible to directly call class methods from the client.  Classes are just syntactic sugars around existing objects.  The documentation on [Private functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication?hl=en#private_functions) clearly says that `obj.objectMethod()` isn't callable  from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the example and for the answer, based on that it seems I am figuring out another way how could I encapsulate functions on server side - actually with an object literal:

```
const appFunctionLibrary = {
 appFunctions: {
  "fun1": function (arg1) {
    return arg1
  },
  "fun2": function (arg1, arg2) {
    return [arg1, arg2]
  },
  "fun3": function () {
    return "fun without param"
  }
 }
}

const main = requestedFunction =>
appFunctionLibrary.appFunctions[requestedFunction.name] 
(requestedFunction.arguments)
```

Calling from client side /1 way: also create an "object" in client script and call ../:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <button type="button" onclick="clientObject.clientFun.call(clientObject)">Test</button>
    <script>
      function ClientObj() {
       this.clientFun = function(){
        let arg1 = 'hello'
        let arg2 = 'from client'

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function onSuccess(msg) {
          console.log(msg)
        }).main({name:'fun2', arguments: `${arg1}, ${arg2}`})  // .main({name:'fun3', arguments: ""}) .main({name:'fun1', arguments:  `${arg1}`})
       }
      }
      clientObject = new ClientObj()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes this is another way to call object methods if there is a long list of methods.  It would help others if you showed how you call this server side function from the client with `requestedFunction.name`

Comment: please, see above my edited answer with client side call..